# VB.NET - Searching Outlook Email Subject Line

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I'm trying to create a piece of code that is monitoring an outlook inbox for a specific email (The code sends an email to its own email address and expects to receive that email). I need to be able to search the email inbox for a specific subject.

I've taken a look at the only relevant question I could find here - [Searching For Phone Numbers In Email Subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148207/searching-for-phone-numbers-in-email-subject-line), but it doesn't compile in VB.NET, the line:

`Set sch = Application.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF)` isn't agreed with.

Is there a way to do this? My aim is to send the email and run this code periodically on a `BackgroundWorker` until the email is seen (timing out after so many attempts). I just can't find a way to read the subject line.

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1**

Just clear up what the issue is:

Visual Studio is automatically removing `set`. The problem is with the `Application.AdvancedSearch`, I get the error:

> 'AdvancedSearch' is not a member of 'Systems.Windows.Form.Application'

**Edit 2**

Updated code to this:

```
 Sub TestAdvancedSearchComplete()
        Dim ap As Outlook.Application
        Dim sch As Outlook.Search
        Dim rsts As Outlook.Results
        Dim i As Integer
        blnSearchComp = False
        Const strF As String = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE '%###%'"
        Const strS As String = "Inbox"
        sch = ap.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF)
        While blnSearchComp = False
            Application.DoEvents()
        End While
        rsts = sch.Results
        For i = 1 To rsts.Count
            MsgBox(rsts.Item(i).SenderName)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Code is now compiling OK, but showing that `ap` has not yet been assigned a value, I guess I need to assign it a value referencing the outlook application?

Comment: Did you try replacing `Set` with `Dim`?

Comment: @ProGrammer Please see updated question

Comment: Application refers to an instance of the Ouitlook.Application object. Did you declare and initialize that object?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko thanks, I've updated my question thanks to your comment

Comment: Yes, you do need to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Items.ItemAdd event on the Inbox folder - the new item will be passed as an argument to your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

regarding the "ap has not yet been assigned a value" issue, you need to create an Outlook application object like this:

```
Dim ap As Outlook.Application = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
```

That worked for me.